# Is it possible to compile Symfony2 assetic:dump and deploy that rather than run it on the server?

Tags: php, deployment, symfony, assetic, capifony

I have a problem on my production server where `assetic:dump` is timing out on a Capifony deploy (but not always).

Running `assetic:dump` locally is fine. Also deploying to a different staging (much less powerful) server is fine.

To fix this (and speed up deploy), I was wondering whether it's possible to run `assetic:dump` before a deployment and just send those complied assets along with the rest of the deployment?

Comment: Have you tried my solution ? I believe it's my best contribution to S.O., so I'd be glad to have it accepted if it worked :-)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That's a bit tricky, I'm also trying to do this (java is not working properly on my server, so deployment fails).

The problem is that Capifony deploys from a source control repository, and usually dumped assets are not on the repository (and they shouldn't).

So I guess the only way to do this is to create a Capistrano task (Capifony is based on Capistrano) that will dump the assets and rsync them on the server.

**Edit :** Here's my attempt
**Edit :** It does work, I've been using it since I answered the question.

I'm sure there are plenty of possible improvements, I'm not a ruby guy, I'm not a shell script guy either.

In your deploy.rb you can add two tasks :

```
before "deploy:update_code", "deploy:dump_assetic_locally"
after "deploy:update_code", "deploy:rsync_local_assets_to_server"
```

And the code associated to those tasks (in the same file) :

```
namespace :deploy do
  task :dump_assetic_locally, :roles => :web do
    run_locally "php app/console assetic:dump --env=prod"
  end

  task :rsync_local_assets_to_server, :roles => :web do
    finder_options = {:except => { :no_release => true }}
    find_servers(finder_options).each {|s| run_locally "rsync -az --delete --rsh='ssh -p #{ssh_port(s)}' #{local_web_path}/js/ #{rsync_host(s)}:#{release_path}/web/js/" }
    find_servers(finder_options).each {|s| run_locally "rsync -az --delete --rsh='ssh -p #{ssh_port(s)}' #{local_web_path}/css/ #{rsync_host(s)}:#{release_path}/web/css/" }
  end

  def local_web_path
    File.expand_path("web")
  end

  def rsync_host(server)
    :user ? "#{user}@#{server.host}" : server.host
  end

  def ssh_port(server)
    server.port || ssh_options[:port] || 22
  end

end
```

Answer (score 0):

The command `assetic:dump` takes the assets from all the bundles avaiable in the current environment and places them in `web/bundles` (or where you tell it to). There should be no problem in doing this locally and then just moving the files.

You should run the command with the `env=prod` option to ensure all bundles which are needed in production are getting generated. You migh also want to clean the `web/bundles` before running the command so the assets for bundles which are only used in development (e.g. profiler) are not present.

I would simply do a test by running the command locally, download the assets from production and compare them. I cannot think of anything right now as css and js gets served to the client and should not be different when generated on different machines, but I might be wrong.

Answer (score -1):

Is very simple
add to your `deploy.rb`

```
set :dump_assetic_assets, true
```